# Anomaly in accuracy calculation

Tags: matlab, confusion-matrix

I am classifying a dataset with four classes using pretrained VGG19. To calculate accuracy, I used this formula:

`accuracy = sum(predictedLabels==testLabels)/numel(predictedLabels)` **--Eq 1**

Then I calculated the confusion matrix using:

```
confMat = confusionmat(testLabels, predictedLabels) **--Eq 2**
```

From which I got a matrix with 4 rows and 4 columns since I had 4 classes.

Now, we know that the accuracy formula is also:

```
Accuracy=TP+TN/(TP+TN+FP+FN) **Eq-3**
```

So I also calculated Accuracy from my confusion matrix formed through above **Eq. 2**. where
`TP=value in (row==column), 
FP=sum of column-TP, 
FN=sum of row-TP, 
TN=sum of the diagonal-TP`

If I am doing above steps alright, then my confusion is that I am getting different accuracies from two methods **Eq 1 and Eq 3**. The accuracy I am getting with Eq. 1 is equivalent to the formula `TP/(TP+TN)`. so, If this is the case, then Eq. 1 is the wrong formula for calculating accuracy. But, this formula has been used across all matlab deep learning codes. 
So, MATLAB is doing something wrong (which has the probability 0, I know) or I am doing something wrong. But, unfortunately, I am unable to pinpoint my mistake.

Now, the question is,

Am I doing it wrong? Where am I missing the step? How to correct it? What is the logical explanation of this anomaly?

**EDIT**

This anomaly in accuracy calculation happens due to class imbalance problem. that is when, there are different number of samples in each class. therefore, the regular accuracy formula in Eq. 3 will not work in such cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that negative and positive is for prediction (is this a cat or not), while you are doing classification with more than two categories. The classifier doesn't give you positive and negative (for is it a cat prediction), so it is not possible to relate to answers as true positive or false positive etc. Therefore equation 3 is meaningless, and so is the method for computing TP, TN etc. For example, if TP is row=column as you defined, then these are the accurate values in the diagonal of confMat. But what is TN? According to your definition it is TP (which is the diagonal) minus the diagonal. I hope this helps put things on the write track.

Comment: I couldn't quite understand what you said. However, I knew that I was calculating TN wrong. So, I looked up some more articles on confusion matrix and hence, came to a conclusion that accuracy formula changes when it is a multi class problem. So, yes, you were correct in pointing out that I was calculating TN wrong.